# Add checkbox to Ubercart checkout

Tags: ubercart, commerce

It sounds quite easy, adding a checkbox to Ubercart's checkout form. The consultant I spoke to told be to use hooks, or try using the [uc_extra_fields_pane](https://drupal.org/project/uc_extra_fields_pane) module, which I also cannot get to work properly (it's config page is not showing up). I'm using Ubercart 2 and Drupal 7.22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom module use the hooks defined in the [Ubercart terms and conditions](https://drupal.org/project/uc_tc) module.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I edited this module to fit my needs, thanks a lot!